# how to convert a string to object's property which it's an object too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a little multi language change, here is the code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/xra81qg6/11/)
html and jQuery:

```js
var dict = {
 fr: {
   'hello' : 'Bonjour',
        'bye' : 'Au revoir'
  },
  en: {
   'hello' : 'Hello',
        'bye' : 'Bye'
  }
};

function text (lang){
 $('h1').html(dict.lang.hello);
        $('p').html(dict.lang.bye);
};

$('a').click(function (){
 var selected = $(this).attr('title');
        text(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/" title="fr">fr</a>
<a href="#/" title="en">en</a>
<h1>Bonjour</h1>
<p>Au revoir</p>
```

What I want is: click the "en" or "fr" to change text from the "dict" object, I stored the "title" of the `<a>` tag, but when I put it to the function "text" as parameter, the console shows **"TypeError: dict.lang is undefined"**, I understand that the `var selected` is a string, it can't not replace the "fr" and "en" in the object.
So here is the question:
**how to convert a string to object's property which it's an object too?**

Comment: there are no `lang` prop on `dict` variable!

Comment: Using brackets notation: `dict[lang].hello`   https://jsfiddle.net/xra81qg6/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it as `dict[lang].hello` and  `dict[lang].bye`

```js
var dict = {
 fr: {
   'hello' : 'Bonjour',
        'bye' : 'Au revoir'
  },
  en: {
   'hello' : 'Hello',
        'bye' : 'Bye'
  }
};

function text (lang){
 $('h1').html(dict[lang].hello);
        $('p').html(dict[lang].bye);
};

$('a').click(function (){
 var selected = $(this).attr('title');
        text(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/" title="fr">fr</a>
<a href="#/" title="en">en</a>
<h1>Bonjour</h1>
<p>Au revoir</p>
```

Comment: It works ! Just a syntaxe error, I was into a complicate way.

Comment: No problem . Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since, there are not `lang` props on your `dict` variabel. so you need to remove it.

Refers from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html), you can accessing props of object as associative array. as example: `array["name"]["nameagain"].id;`

so for your case, you can call it using: `dict[lang]` to get the object, or `dict[lang].bye` as particular data.

See my snippet below:

```js
var dict = {
 fr: {
   'hello' : 'Bonjour',
        'bye' : 'Au revoir'
  },
  en: {
   'hello' : 'Hello',
        'bye' : 'Bye'
  }
};

function text (lang){
 $('h1').html(dict[lang].hello);
        $('p').html(dict[lang].bye);
};

$('a').click(function (){
 var selected = $(this).attr('title');
        text(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/" title="fr">fr</a>
<a href="#/" title="en">en</a>
<h1>Bonjour</h1>
<p>Au revoir</p>
```

Comment: yes, it works ! Just a syntaxe error, I will remember this !